# glossaries does not work

Tags: pdf, glossaries

At some point glossaries stopped compiling glossaries. I thought something was wrong in my preamble, but now I am not sure because of the following minimum working example which yields 1 blank pdf.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\begin{document}
Here's my \gls{ex} term.
\end{document}
```

**Log File**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./labrat.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compat
ible-307.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypern
av.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.s
ty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.
sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.s
ty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)) (./labrat.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./labrat.aux
) )
Output written on labrat.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on labrat.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on labrat.log.
```

Comment: You MWE didn't blank for me. It yield this line `Here’s my sample term` .

Comment: No Glossary entry and article?

Comment: Did you actually run makeglossaries kor whatever the program is called)?